# What rabbis openly allowed/promoted wearing wigs?

Tags: sources-mekorot, halacha-theory, rabbis, tznius-modesty, hair-covering

When discussing wigs as a means of covering women's hair, I only heard that rabbis recognized them only aposteriori.

What prominent rabbis publicly allowed their use apriori?

Comment: It might be a hard find. The first one commonly known to discuss the issue is the Shiltei Giborim in Shabbos. https://www.sefaria.org/Shiltei_HaGiborim_on_Shabbat.29a.1?lang=bi  And he himself seems to indicate that he’s finding a heter for the women who were already wearing it.

Comment: You want a Rabbi who lived in a community where no one wore wigs, and he announced they were permitted? Otherwise any discussion about wigs will always be after the fact that people are wearing them. Or you want an allowance that explicitly doesn't care that people are in fact wearing them?

Comment: the Lubavitcher Rebbe? https://www.chabad.org/theJewishWoman/article_cdo/aid/840202/jewish/The-Rebbe-on-the-Jewish-Womans-Hair-Covering.htm